# Let G be a group of order 1001 then number of abelian group upto isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

1. 1
2. 3
3. 7
4. 11

I did not understand the meaning of question specifically the statement "up to isomorphic" means?
Also is their any set formula to find number of abelian groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1001=7\times 11 \times 13$, since this number is square free the only abelian group of order $1001$ is cyclic.

Comment: Does the statement 'up to isomorphic' mean That group of order 1001 becomes isomorphic to some abelian group?

Comment: it means that if you have two isomorphic groups you don't count them twice

Comment: What if the number would be 1000?

Comment: then it is harder, since $1000=2^3 \times 5^3$ you want $P(3)\times P(3)=3^2=9$, where $P$ is the partition function. You may want to look up the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.

Comment: P(3)=3 because 3 can be expressed in 3 ways, {3,2+1,1+1+1} ryt?..and so P(4)=5

Comment: yes exactly.${}{}{}$

Comment: Okay, thank u so much

Comment: happy to help. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

Use the prime factorisation of 1001.